# Rational cohomological dimension of the lattices in $SL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory, cohomological-dimension

What is the rational cohomological dimension of the lattices in $SL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, where $n\geq 3$ ? A reference would be appreciated.

For the definition of "cohomological dimension of a group over ring"  one can look at here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomological_dimension, and the term `rational cohomological dimension' is used when the ring is taken as the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It would help if you gave examples, since the term "lattice" has a different flavor when the field is real or global or $p$-adic.   And the term "rational cohomological dimension" may not be familiar to everybody without a little explanation.

Comment: If a lattice is a discrete cocompact subgroup, the Bruhat-Tits building for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf Q_p)$ having dimension $n-1$, it cannot be more than that. Such a lattice is known (at least when $n\geq 3$) to be arithmetic, and Borel and Serre have produced, for an arithmetic subgroup, a module $M$ such that $H_{n-1}(\Gamma,M)\neq 0$. References are to be found in the books on buildings and cohomology of groups by Kenneth Brown ...

Comment: A lattice means here "discrete subgroup of finite covolume"; since in SL($n$,$\mathbf{Q}_p$) they are all cocompact, the argument of few_reps shows that it's $\le n-1$ and actually it's indeed very probably $n-1$ (e.g., because they always contain some copy of $\mathbf{Z}^{n-1}$ acting cocompactly on a flat).

Comment: @YCor : I made as if the definition of the cohomological dimension used in the OP is the virtual cohomological dimension for which Borel-Serre dualizing module give a definitive answer ... but it asks for the group to be arithmetic and this is hard to prove (I never studied the proof but it doesn't seem trivial). So your argument would certainly be more natural, (and as definitive since virtual cohomological dimension is monotone with respect to inclusions) but ... how do you exhibit such a $\mathbf Z^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: I don't know if it uses arithmeticity, or just some general fact about cocompact actions on CAT(0) complexes.

Comment: @YCor Would you have a reference ?

Comment: No, I'm not even sure the argument works.

Comment: If we write the lattice as $G(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$ with $G$ $\mathbf{R}$-anisotropic and $G(\mathbf{Q}_p)\simeq\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, and if $H$ is a maximal torus achieving the $\mathbf{Q}_p$-rank ($=n-1$) and is $\mathbf{Q}$-defined, then $T(\mathbf{Z}[1/p]))$ is a lattice (since $T$ is $\mathbf{R}$-anisotropic) inside $T(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, so contains a copy of $\mathbf{Z}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @YCor : thanks ... (I'm not sure I can see how to prove the existence of such a torus .. it seems to be ok by the construction of classical groups as unitary groups ... or is there a direct argument ?)

Comment: Here: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf (Reductive groups schemes, lectures by Conrad), we have: if char($K$) is 0, every linear algebraic group has the property that any K-defined torus is contained in a maximal torus that is K-defined. So this boils down to proving the existence of a maximal $\mathbf{Q}_p$-split torus that is defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: PS what I quote from Conrad is in A.1.2 of the above link

Comment: @ Ycor and few_reps: Thanks a lot for these helpful suggestions and discussions.

Comment: @YCor : thanks especially for the complete answer and for giving the reference of `Reductive groups schemes' by Conrad.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Yes, you are right. I should have given some explanation of the term `rational cohomological dimension'. I am adding it in the edited version.